# What is Excel #N/A error abbreviation, looking for?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

In MS-Excel we have below functions return errors:

> > ### #N/A #REF! #NAME? #DIV/0! #NULL! #VALUE! #NUM!

I think about what is the complete error massage, which each one are represents?

Of course, seams the #N/A one is abbreviation of two words. What is "N" and "A" looking for?

Comment: *What is "N" and "A" looking for?* Not Available.

Comment: The title indicates this is just about #N/A.  The body suggests that you might be asking about all of the error messages.  This information is readily available in Excel help or with a Google search.  Can you clarify what you're looking for that is unclear?

Comment: @fixer1234Specially I need reference for **What is #N/A stands for?** and I bring the list of the Excel errors with special note at **#N/A** meaning need. Regards.

Comment: @Akina, Please bring a reference for this mean. @ fixer1234, I so studied some general helps and did search in google, bot nothing found about the "What is **#N/A** stands for". If you now, please prefer a reference. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Each Error has a meaning & reason.**

For example:

**#N/A,** stands for **Not Available** and indicates that, *the Formula cannot finds the referenced data*.

**#Ref!,** is **Reference** and indicates that the *reference is invalid.*

**For more information and better understanding check the following Web links.**

https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/excel-error-messages-to-get-to-know/

https://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/formula-errors.htm

Comment: @fixer1234,, it's good idea to include some basic infos along with links,, this is very first time I've used links, since I've found with many answers. ☺

Comment: Regards you, Please prefer a reference for **Not Available** is what is **#N/A** stands for. yours.

Comment: @mgae2m: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-na-function.  What the error codes represent is well documented.  The abbreviations Microsoft chose are arbitrary.  N/A is generally assumed to be derived from "Not Available".  Beyond that, only Microsoft can say the actual basis on which the abbreviations were selected.

Comment: Very truly yours, with best regards.

Comment: @mgae2m,, glad to help you,, keep asking ☺